# Building Static Binary with ODBC in Go

Tags: go, build, odbc

I'm kinda new to the concept of static building in go.

I was trying to build a static binary for Linux that includes ODBC (which needs `cgo`) inside of it and was failing to do that. This is the library I'm trying to build with [alexbrainman/odbc](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc).

I have tried a couple commands, not sure if they even fit the scenario here;

`CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags="-s -w"`

`CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-linkmode external -extldflags "-fno-PIC -static"'`

`CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags '-w -extldflags "-static"'`

They all fail just like running `CGO_ENABLED=0 go build`.

Is this even possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: `odbc` specially says it uses cgo for libodbc, so you cannot built it by disabling cgo.

Comment: @JimB But does this apply to all packages that require cgo or is `odbc` built differently? My understanding is that it's possible to do build static binaries the incorporate such c dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you can statically link c archives, though you are probably going to need a static libc other than glibc for that. The point I was making is that you cannot even try to link any C libraries if you turn off CGO.

Comment: @JimB Gotcha, Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Also when posting please detail what happens when you try something. "They all fail" isn't a lot to go on.